# Why does my Tomato router seem to behave badly as time passes

Tags: iptables, tomato, qos

I've set up a [Firewall script](http://pastebin.com/BVehYz82) on my Tomato router (a WRT54G 2.0, actually) that seems to behave correctly at start, but after one or two days, it seems that the script does not work anymore...

The script marks specific packets using iptables, and sets some qdisc based on those marks. I test the script by starting an FTP upload or download, and checking that the P2P traffic decreases.  This does happen if I've rebooted the router recently, but it does not after one or two days up: the P2P traffic does not decrease any more.

Here are other things I checked...

- CPU load is around 0.2 at most, generally less than 0.1.
- 3.5MB of RAM are free, over a total of 16MB
- Number of connections is between 500 and 550, with a max at 4096.

I tried to telnet into the router and grep /proc/net/ip_conntrack to check if the marks were correctly set, but all connections have 'mark=0' even right after a reboot, when the router behaves as I expect it. I therefore suppose that marks set by iptables are not supposed to appear here. Correct?

What other commands may give me some hints about this behavior?

I know very well that the script needs quite some work, but I'd like it to behave correctly before I change it...